# Alt/Option key as meta on Mac for Racket GUI

Tags: scheme, racket

I saw this thread: http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2010-August/041085.html

I'm just wondering whether the problem has been solved..

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the mailing list (also, I don't think it's been resolved). You're much more likely to get an answer there. Also, if it hasn't been resolved yet, it'll remind the relevant people.